# Exit Relay Bandwidth Data not showing on Tor Globe or Atlas

Tags: exit-relays, bandwidth, atlas

I recently set up a Tor exit relay on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS server, using a VPS.  It's running fine, with an average throughput of about 1 MB/s, and shows up OK on Tor Atlas and Tor Globe.  To try to avoid possible DMCA takedown notices to my VPS provider, I set it up using Tor's restricted exit policy, and set the ufw firewall to allow in only the corresponding ports.  To restrict possible torrent traffic further, I found and implemented a set of iptables rules that look for and drop traffic containing characteristic BitTorrent signatures.  At that point, it all worked fine, and Globe and Atlas showed the relay bandwidth.

However, the server became infected through a WordPress/Apache site that I also ran on it, and provoked comment spam complaints, so I rebuilt it, dropping the WordPress site this time.  I set up Tor as before, but this time I thought I would be clever and set up the firewall to drop UDP traffic on most of the ports except the Tor-related ones (9001 and 9030), again to suppress torrent traffic.  In fact, I went even further and explicitly denied all outgoing ports as well, allowing only those in the exit policy.   Now the relay (PercontorQuick) still shows up on Atlas and Globe (flags Exit / Fast / Guard / Running / Stable / Valid), but no bandwidth data is displayed, just the message: "No data available :(".  My Linode dashboard still shows a healthy 1 MB/s throughput, so the relay is actually working.  At this point, it has been running for over 4 days since the last restart, and quite a few days before that.

I have also removed the UDP restriction on ports 53, 80, and 443, incoming and outgoing, with no effect.  Just to be clear, I have restarted Tor and reloaded the firewall, obviously.  Equally obviously, I have been too clever.  Can anyone please tell me how to restore the provision of data to the Globe/Atlas bandwidth display?  If not, I guess I will just have to reset the firewall and go through the tedious process of setting it up again, without fussing about UDP traffic this time.  Or just do without the Globe/Atlas data.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you switch from using the distro-packaged version of tor to the repos from the tor project when you rebuilt?  I've run into a similar problem, and I'm trying to see if they're related.

Comment: I have the same issue after I re-setup my Raspberry Pi. I upgraded Raspian to 'Jessie' (Sept-2015) and installed TOR 0.2.5.12 from the distro repositories. Since then globe.torproject does not show any bandwidth for 3 days or 1 week. However, when selecting 1 Month it shows details as it should.

Comment: The relay does not exist anymore, so I'll close the question.